# How can I do a simple query to Solr?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

## TL;DR

I can't make the simplest query in Solr, like searching for the word `game` over a list of documents (for example books).

I'm following the tutorials [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/tutorial-techproducts.html) but I think they are a bit outdated. I'm doing it in docker.

## My setup, in docker

### 1. Setup the data dir

First, I prepare a storage by creating an empty directory and making it `777` to avoid any permission problems:

```
$ mkdir solrdata         # To make a storage that I can inspect
$ chmod 777 solrdata     # Because I'm user 1000 and the docker runs with user 8983
```

### 2. docker run

Then I run the docker:

```
$ docker run --rm -d -v ${PWD}/solrdata:/var/solr -p 8983:8983 --name solr-test solr
```

I check it works by going to http://localhost:8983 and I see the admin panel. If I go to the cores list, I see it empty, which is normal:

[image: See the admin panel]

### 3. Creation of a sample core

I create a core named `sample_core` by doing this from the command line:

```
$ docker exec solr-test solr create_core -c sample_core
```

I see the core created by going to the admin panel and refreshing. Its data is shown and also it appears in the dropdown to be selected to work with it:

[image: Core is shown]

### 4. Load sample data

To load the sample data I bash-in the docker to issue a `bin/post` command:

```
host$ docker exec -it solr-test bash
container$ bin/post -c sample_core example/exampledocs/*
```

### 5. Checking data is loaded

If I go to the admin panel, select the core `sample_core` and issue an empty query (ie: `q=*:*`) I see there are documents stored, like for example the book "A Game of Thrones" among others:

[image: List of results]

If I load in the browser the raw query like this: http://localhost:8983/solr/sample_core/select?q=*:* it also works.

### 6. Trying to query a term (FAILS ⚠️❌)

When I search for the word `game` in the frontend the result is an empty list. I'd expect Solr returned "at least" the book "A Game of Thrones", shouldn't it?

[image: Empty list]

This also happens if I change my query string directly in the browser like this: http://localhost:8983/solr/sample_core/select?q=game

Nevertheless, according to the documentation it shoud work:

[image: documentation excerpt]

## Question

What should I do to have a simple docker setup single-node where I load a ton documents and I want to search for them with fuzzy text over any field?

Comment: I think the answer by Mats answers your question, but if the terms that he is mentioned are not familiar to you check out this Solr tutorial: https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies (full disclosure I wrote it)

Comment: Hey! Will check your tuto out, as the official documentation is a bit outdated, I think! Thanks, will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

When you're just using `game` by itself, you're searching in whatever field is defined as the default search field - that might not be the field you're thinking of. Some (example) schemas has `copyField` instruction that copies every submitted field into a common field named `_text_`, and then uses that field as the default search field.

However, if you don't have that instruction present or the default search field (`df` for the standard query parser or `qf` for `edismax`) is set to another field, you won't get any hits.

To search against a specific field you can instead prefix your query with the field name:

```
q=name:game
```

This will search for the text (or more exact, the token(s) resulting form the text) `game` in the field `name`. If the field you've included is a defined as a common `text_en` field, you should get a hit. If not, use the `Analysis` page under the admin interface to see how text gets processed both when indexing and querying - the same token(s) need to be present on both sides for a hit to occur.

You can also use the `edismax` query handler to get the more common user search query behavior:

```
q=game&qf=name
```

.. says that Solr should try to match `game` in the field `name` (qf => query fields). You can include more than one field, i.e. `qf=name author`, and you can prioritize how you want them scored: `qf=name^10 author` would score hits in `name` ten times higher than what they'd do with author (i.e. the score from a hit in `name` would be multiplied by 10 - however, the hits in `name` could be more common, resulting a lower score totally. You can append `debug=all` to see exact scoring information).

Comment: Will try and will come back with selecting the answer if it works for me! Thnks.